# Variance of a linear estimator

Tags: regression, mathematical-statistics, variance, estimators, unbiased-estimator

There is a theorem ([here](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1710.04055.pdf), Theorem 3.2.) which says: Let $x_i \sim p_i(\mu_i, \sigma_i^2)$  for $1 \leq i \leq n$ be a set of pairwise uncorrelated random variables. Consider the linear estimator $y_{n,\alpha}(x_1, ..., x_n) = \sum_{i = 1}^n \alpha_i x_i$, where $\sum_{i = 1}^n \alpha_i = 1$. Then, the variance of the estimator is minimized for (its proof can be also found in this [question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/133072/finding-an-unbiased-estimator-with-the-smallest-variance)):

$$\alpha_i = \frac{\sigma_i^{-2}}{\sum_{j = 1}^n \sigma_j^{-2}}.$$

My question is: In another, but somehow similar context (but not minimization), I have obtained numerically, for my problem at hand, that: $$\alpha_i = \frac{\sigma_i^{-1}}{\sum_{j = 1}^n \sigma_j^{-1}}.$$ I really appreciate that people familiar with statistics could elaborate that if my obtained formula is known in other context, or what is the meaning behind that if we want to compare it with  the known formula in the above theorem. In other words, if the $\alpha_i$ in the theorem minimizes the variance of the estimator, what is the interpretation of my $\alpha_i$?

**EDIT**

In general, where $\alpha_i = \frac{\sigma_i^{-2}}{\sum_{j = 1}^n \sigma_j^{-2}}$ minimizes the variance of the estimator, if we decrease the exponent from $-2$ to $-3$ or increase it from $-2$ to $-1$, how the variance of estimator will change? In particular, which is my main question, whether $-1$ is a special value like $-2$.

Comment: There is one obvious interpretation of your formula: it is an error.  Apart from that, what kind of answer are you hoping to receive?  You seem not to have a definite question.

Comment: @whuber Thanks for your comment. I have a linear estimator and have obtained the weights, i.e., $\alpha_i$'s, for different situations. The exponents of $\sigma_i$'s in the formula for $\alpha_i$'s are always between $-1$ and $-2$. Now, I know what the lower bound, that is, $-2$, means, which minimizes the variance of the estimator. I'm wondering if the upper bound, i.e., $-1$, has a special interpretation.

Comment: How do the situations vary and how exactly do you obtain the weights?

Comment: @whuber I have different sets of random variables correspond to different scenarios within the context of biology. I have interpreted the $\alpha_i$'s as probabilities of cell sensors and have related $y$ to some biological quantities, so essentially I have obtained a linear estimator, in analogy with statistics. From experiments, I have the values of $\alpha_i$'s and have found their forms as stated in my question. Interestingly, it is very similar to well-established concepts in statistics but I don't know how to interpret the $-1$ value.

Comment: @whuber I just found that the Jeffreys prior for the standard deviation in normal distribution is proportional to $1/\sigma$. Do you think that is it relevant to my $\alpha_i$?